# Flutter - The builder for route "null" returned null

Tags: flutter, dart, navigation

I'm new to flutter and I tried the previous solution to the same question but that did not help.
In the below code, when i click on the add icon, i need to navigate to another page where i'll add the data. but im getting an error, even though i have added the return statement in MaterialPageRoute.

Companies.dart -

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './Object.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import './Detail_Pages/Company_details.dart';
import './Add object Popup/add_company.dart';

class Companies extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CompaniesState createState() => _CompaniesState();
}

class _CompaniesState extends State<Companies> {
  GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  Future<List<Company>> _getCompanies() async {
    var data = await http.get("http://localhost/crm_demo/getData.php");
    var jsonData = json.decode(data.body);
    List<Company> companies = [];
    for (var c in jsonData) {
      Company company = Company(
          c["name"],
          c["address"],
          c["opportunities"],
          c["pipelineRevenue"],
          c["revenueAchieved"],
          c["city"],
          c["state"],
          c["country"],
          c["zipcode"],
          c["phone"],
          c["timezone"],
          c["tags"]);
      companies.add(company);
    }
    return companies;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            "Companies",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
          ),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                    return addCompany();
                  }));
                })
          ],
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(...)
```

add_Company.dart -

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../Object.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import '../Detail_Pages/Company_details.dart';

class addCompany extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _addCompanyState createState() => _addCompanyState();
}

class _addCompanyState extends State<addCompany> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          )
        ],
        title: Text("Add New Contact"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Error (The only error i got)

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The builder for route "null" returned null.
The relevant error-causing widget was
    MaterialApp
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```dart
Navigator.push(context,
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) {
  return addCompany();
}));
```

Use this:

```dart
Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => addCompany()),
);
```

And you may ask: "Isn't it the same thing?". No. Simply because on the first one you are declaring some variable context of the `BuildContext` type. Therefore, you are not using your context variable, responsible for the navigation part. If you look carefully, you need to use `context` only, as it is passed onto the build method, previously.

The large arrow is the same as one line brackets.

Comment: @VishalPrabhu can you post the whole exception that was caught?

Comment: that's all i got, whatever i have pasted under error in the above question.

Comment: @VishalPrabhu then I'm afraid that I can't answer the problem. That error can even be from the MaterialApp() Widget, if you have it on the start of the Widget tree.

Answer (score 0):

The solution which @VishalPrabhu mentioned should work. If not, try doing the same thing with a different approach.
Step 1 - Rename the class name addCompany to AddCompany.
Step 2 - Define a method for navigation.

```
void changeScreen(BuildContext context, Widget widget) {
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => widget));
}
```

Step 3 -  Call the method in where screen navigation is required.

```
changeScreen(context, AddCompany());
```

**Update futter and dart to the latest versions.